# Auto extract values in the passed parameter

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class

Say:

```
case class point(x: Double, y: Double)
```

Is there a way to do:

```
def test(p: point) = {
  val point(x, y) = p // extract x,y from point. I want to make this automatic
  x + y
}
```

In a concise way, say like:

```
def test(point(x, y)) = x + y
```

This of course isn't valid syntax.

Is there a way to make a function automatically extract values from a case class like that?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803222/is-there-any-fundamental-limitations-that-stops-scala-from-implementing-pattern In short -- no, such syntax do not exists in scala.

Comment: @om-nom-nom yeah, that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
def test(p: point) = p match{case point(x,y)=>x+y}
```

Comment: that even more wordy than op's initial code (`val point(x, y) = p`) and does not solves problem in any way

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
case class point(x: Double, y: Double) {
    def sum = x + y // OMG IT WORKS!
}
```

Comment: Soooo, you just added yet another layer of indirection? Instead of using point extractor (automatically provided by scalac), I have to convert it to tuple, which is unpacked then. How it's better than original code?

Comment: Just another way to mess your code :) Why do you need this?

Comment: You want to switch the context and magically to get access to methods of an object? Like new point(1, 2) { x + y }?

Comment: I didn't get your last comments. See, [original code already works](http://scalafiddle.net/console/b27d5296bede63b1493a5d321d4e8092), but op wants to go extra mile and have it more concise without need to write additional code (thus, the word *automatically*). What you propose works as well, but 1) adds more code 2) adds yet another conversion step

Comment: Why not just write a class method? Everything will work as you want.

Comment: because it's not only this particular situation, but syntax as whole. We love case classes because smarty compiler can write extractors, hashcodes, toString and copy methods, meanwhile, all this stuff is possible to write by hand. We love smarty compiler being able to infer types, even though, we can sit down and annotate every value by ourselves.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: Case class can perfectly have methods and it will not break anything like hashcodes. Sometimes compiler has to be strict to understand your intentions. :)