# pattern matching on function parameters in scala

Tags: scala, function, functional-programming, pattern-matching

Is it possible to pattern match on function heads in scala?

For example, can I write something along the lines of:

```
def myFunction(a:: b:: xs): Int = ???
def myFunction(a:: xs): Int = ???
def myFunction(List.empty): Int = ???
```

Comment: cool idea, but sadly no - the problem is you can only define a function with a specific signature once (there is nothing in the compiler to sugar this up for you). You can of course have `def foo(ls) = ls match { ..`

Comment: thanks. this works in Erlang, so I was hoping there was an equivalent to avoid nested case statements.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803222/is-there-any-fundamental-limitations-that-stops-scala-from-implementing-pattern/14810638#14810638

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use partial functions for this case. Example:

```
  val myFunctionCase1: PartialFunction[List[Int], Int] = {
    case a :: b :: xs => ???
  }

  val myFunctionCase2: PartialFunction[List[Int], Int] = {
    case a :: xs => ???
  }

  val myFunctionCase3: PartialFunction[List[Int], Int] = {
    case Nil => ???
  }

  // compose functions
  val myFunction: List[Int] => Int = 
              myFunctionCase1 orElse myFunctionCase2 orElse myFunctionCase3
```

Usage examples:

```
myFunctionCase1(List(1,2,3))    // invoke
myFunctionCase1(List(1))        // throw MatchError
myFunctionCase2(List(1))        // invoke
...

myFunction(List(1,2,3))
myFunction(List(1))    
myFunction(Nil)
...
```

Comment: It is not necessary to define several partial functions, a partial function can have multiple cases just as a match expression. (And I don't see the need to have the cases separately here). I would however prefer to write a normal definition and use a match expression in this case, i.e. def func(l: List[Int]) = l match { ... }